# Strange behaviour ggplotly and geom_hline in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I want to plot `geom_hline()` on a fixed value in each facet I create with `ggplotly`. When I only plot the `ggplot` plot (with example data) I get the right results:

[image]

But when I want to turn it in a interactive plot through a `ggplotly` object some facets won't show the `geom_hline()`(notice in the ggplot2 code I used a `coord_flip()`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggplotly)

example_df <- structure(list(dbc = c("040201021", "069899282", "129999093", 
"131999277", "159999033", "219799011", "990003025", "991900003", 
"040201021", "069899282", "129999093", "131999277", "159999033", 
"219799011", "990003025", "991900003"), kind = c("max", "max", 
"max", "max", "max", "max", "max", "max", "min", "min", "min", 
"min", "min", "min", "min", "min"), price = c(2518, 831, 2027, 
829, 879, 609, 774, 709, 81, 20, 112, 40, 31, 39, 2, 41)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

plot <- example_df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(0 , price, label = kind)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 385) +
  geom_quasirandom(shape = 21,
             color = pointer_palette("paars"),
             fill = "white",
             size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~ dbc,
             scales = "free",
             ncol = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "prijsafspraak in euro's")

ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("label", "price"))
```

You see that some facets don't have the `geom_hline()` plotted. Is this a bug in plotly or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: without knowing ggplotly so much, I assume there is simply a scaling problem - here different scales for each facet. Try to use the same scales and if this solves the problem

Comment: I've encountered several (ggplot to plotly) translation problems with things like this and annotations and subtitles.  If you don't find an answer easily, it might be quicker to build the graph in with plotly directly, instead of relying on `ggplotly()` to translate correctly.